# xmlstarlet delete element if string found tag

Tags: xmlstarlet

I need to delete entire cellNote element below if epm_default_cloud_admin is found in any tag, tried different things with xmlstarlet and it won;t happen, can you help?

```
<cell>
<cellNote>
 <DIM1>Actual</DIM1>
 <author>epm_default_cloud_admin</author>
 <modified>2016-11-16 08:28:38.0</modified>
 <title></title>
</cellNote>
<cellNote>
 <DIM1>Actual</DIM1>
 <contents>Variance in meals is due to Annual Sales Conference</contents>
 <author>Frank</author>
 <modified>2016-12-23 20:10:13.0</modified>
 <title></title>
</cellNote>
<cell>
```

few things I tried below:

```
xmlstarlet ed -a "/cell/cellNote" --type elem -n string -v "epm_default_cloud_admin"
xmlstarlet ed -d '/cell/cellNote/author[. = 'epm_default_cloud_admin']'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, to deal with a valid xml - ensure that `cell` tag has both opening and closing tag (your input contain both as opening `<cell>`).

**xmlstarlet** solution:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d "//cellNote[*[contains(text(),'epm_default_cloud_admin')]]" input.xml
```

The output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cell>
  <cellNote>
    <DIM1>Actual</DIM1>
    <contents>Variance in meals is due to Annual Sales Conference</contents>
    <author>Frank</author>
    <modified>2016-12-23 20:10:13.0</modified>
    <title/>
  </cellNote>
</cell>
```

Comment: @darknight1906 - You were also close with your second try: `xmlstarlet ed -d "/cell/cellNote[author = 'epm_default_cloud_admin']"`

Comment: @DanielHaley, he was close, but the condition was *if epm_default_cloud_admin is found in **any** tag*

Comment: Thanks @DanielHaley, your solution too works very well.